# How order by with IN clause is works in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running below query in `spark.sql` which has `IN` clause with `order by` statement

Here is my original data:

[image]

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
    *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY category IN ('TV','laptop'), created_at desc) as rn 
FROM table2
```

**Result:**

[image]

Can you help me to interpret this result? I have added 'TV' and 'laptop' in `IN` clause then it should be at top row *(rn = 1 to 4)*

I have observed same behaviour in Snowflake as well. After adding `IN ('TV','laptop')` in the query getting this unpredicted result.

Answer (score 2):

I have played around this much and then got the logic is when we use `IN` clause it is return binary result `0` or `1`

When I have added `IN ('TV','laptop')` into the query. It will check all the result which has this category and assigned it `1` to those records rest will be `0`. Now based on this binary all the `0` records will come first and the records with `1` due to it is `ASC` by default.

[image]

After removing 'laptop' from query, all the records with `TV` will be ordered at the last due to `TV` ones are set to `1` rest will be set to `0`

[image]

I hope you will get clear understanding from this description.

Comment: This is expected behavior and result will be non deterministic .Also any RDBMS will have same result unless you have unique records .Below is link to support answer: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/ROW-NUMBER-function-causing-Non-deterministic-behavior

Comment: @Anand - Thanks for sharing this document. I have tried to search but didn't found in snowflake docs.